# Print an sqlalchemy row

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

All I'd like to do is print a single row of an sqlalchemy table row.

Say I have:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class ATable(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'atable'  
     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 
     name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
```

Then I'd like to output anything that looks like this:

```
id: 1
name: theRowName
```

Preferable without having to hard code in the table columns, i.e. more generally.

I've tried:

```
 atable = Atable()
 ... #add some values etc.
 print atable
 print str(atable)
 print repr(atable)
 print atable.__table__.c
```

As well as thought about implementing `__str__` and `__repr__`, but they again lack the generality request.

There are many questions on covering a table row into JSON, but that's not really what I want, I care more about the visual output - it doesn't need to be machine readable afterwards.

Comment: Add `__str__` and `__repr__` methods respectively to your model, if you wish to alter the representations.

Comment: Updated with regards to `__str__` and `__repr__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear - you want a general method to print "col: value" without hardcoding the column names? I do not use SQLAlchemy much, but a `__str__` method like this should work:

```
def __str__(self):
    output = ''
    for c in self.__table__.columns:
        output += '{}: {}\n'.format(c.name, getattr(self, c.name))
    return output
```

You can then put that method in a mixin class to use elsewhere in your models.

Comment: Nice, thanks! I ended up making a custom 'printer' which does something similar, though not as elegantly as yours so I will be using your code in my 'printer'. I think I should have been clearer that I had already had a lot of different and changing models and really only one very specific place I wanted to print the rows. So it was less effort having it specific on the outside of the class than change all my models' classes. Thanks again.